# Getting count of all repeated rows in a datatable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am filling a dataset by running a stored procedure, and i am filling a datatable from the dataset.

```
DataSet RawDataSet = DataAccessHelper.RunProcedure("storedprocedureName");
//this will just return the dataset by running the procedure
DataTable RankTable = RawDataSet.Tables[0];
```

The Datatable has the below values:

```
Vicky   Login   6/24/2014
Vicky   Login   6/25/2014
Arun    Game    6/26/2014
Arun    Login   6/27/2014
Kumar   Login   6/28/2014
Kumar   Game    6/29/2014
Arun    Login   6/30/2014
Arun    Login   7/1/2014
Kumar   Game    7/2/2014
Vicky   Login   7/3/2014
Arun    Login   7/4/2014
Arun    Game    7/5/2014
```

I want to parse this dataTable and get how many times everyone has done an action, i.e how many times each row is repeated:

```
Vicky   Login  3
Arun    Game   2
Arun    Login  4
Kumar   Login  1
Kumar   Game   2
```

I am new to C#. This can be done using count(*) in SQL but I need to do this using C#.
Please let me know if there are any ways to achieve this.

I have searched SO but all posts are related to removing the duplicates/finding the duplicates, which does not solve my purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that using LINQ like:

```
var query = RankTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(r => new { Name = r.Field<string>("Name"), Action = r.Field<string>("Action") })
                    .Select(grp => new
                    {
                        Name = grp.Key.Name,
                        Action = grp.Key.Action,
                        Count = grp.Count()
                    });
```

Here `Name` is assumed to be the column name for first column, and `Action` is assumed to be name of second column which has values like login, game etc.

You may see [LINQ to DataSet  - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For output use:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Action: {1}, Count: {2}",item.Name, item.Action,item.Count);
}
```