# Get the total count per department

Tags: .net, visual-studio, linq, datatable

This question is a link to [Count Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387610/getting-count-of-all-repeated-rows-in-a-datatable-in-c-sharp)

I have a output like this:

```
Department    Name     Count
Sales         John     2
Sales         Peter    1
Admin         Jack     1
Admin         Sophia   2
Admin         Jill     1
Maintenance   Bob      2
Maintenance   Henry    1
```

What I want to output using this info is:

```
Department    Name     Count
Sales         John     2
Sales         Peter    1
------------------------
Total                  3
------------------------
Admin         Jack     1
Admin         Sophia   2
Admin         Jill     1
------------------------
Total                  4
------------------------
Maintenance   Bob      2
Maintenance   Henry    1
------------------------
Total                  3
------------------------
```

I'm using the following code to output the first list:

```
var query = data.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => new { Dept = r.Field<string>("Department"),
                    Name = r.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                    Surname = r.Field<string>("LastName")})
                .Select(grp => new
                {
                    Dept = grp.Key.Dept,
                    Name = grp.Key.Name,
                    Surname = grp.Key.Surname,
                    Count = grp.Count()
                });

            foreach(var item in query)
            {
                newData.Rows.Add(item.Dept, item.Name, item.Surname, item.Count);
            }
```

How do I add the total count for every department?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Department"))
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

This will give you a `Dictionary<string, int>` where the keys are the department names and the values are the counts.